# Values not consistently being removed from an array if it's found in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I have the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caffeinatedcoder/y6yvkn1v/) where I am trying to sort a json string of pokemon data into two arrays according to how far they are away from me.

```
var pokemon = JSON.parse(JSONoriginal); //*See JSFiddle link for full JSON String*

//encounter_ids are unique to each spawned pokemon, use these to look for & remove duplicates
    for(var x=0; x <= pokemon.result.length-1; x++){
        var aPokemon = {
                name: pokemon.result[x].pokemon_id,
                encounter_id: pokemon.result[x].encounter_id,
                expiration_timestamp_ms: pokemon.result[x].expiration_timestamp_ms,
                latitude: pokemon.result[x].latitude,
                longitude: pokemon.result[x].longitude
                };
        if(pokemon.result[x].expiration_timestamp_ms === undefined){
            //Check if pokemon's already been put into nearby array, if so then we don't need to do anything
            var a = nearby.filter(function(a){
                return a.encounter_id === aPokemon.encounter_id;
                })[0];
            if(a === undefined){
                //Put in nearby Array because we don't have a location
                nearby.push(aPokemon);
            }
        }else{
            //Check if pokemon's already been put into nearby array, if so then remove it from there
            var b = nearby.filter(function(b){
                return b.encounter_id === aPokemon.encounter_id;
                })[0];
            if(b !== undefined){
                nearby.splice(nearby.indexOf(b),1);
            }
            //Check if pokemon's already been put into immediate array, if so then we don't need to do anything
            var c = immediate.filter(function(c){
                return c.encounter_id === aPokemon.encounter_id;
                })[0];
            if(c === undefined){
                //Put it in immediate Array because we can locate & display them
                immediate.push(aPokemon);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm able to parse my example json string and populate both of my arrays, but it appears that some pokemon are not removed from the `Nearby[]` array when they should be (when they're being put into the `Immediate[]` array). Can anyone spot the error in my logic? How can I get this loop to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the Rattata, Krabby and Squirtle with those IDs in the immediate section should not appear in the nearby section? The problem is you're only checking for duplicates if there is a `expiration_timestamp_ms`, which the second entries don't have.

[Edit]

This should work: check if an entry is already in the immediate array when pushing it to nearby. I've updated your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6yvkn1v/4/):

```
var a = nearby.filter(function(a){
    return a.encounter_id === aPokemon.encounter_id;
    })[0] || immediate.filter(function(c){
    return c.encounter_id === aPokemon.encounter_id;
    })[0];
```

Comment: Correct, they should not appear in the nearby section once they're being placed into the immediate section. You raise a good point, but what should I check for instead?

Comment: That did the trick! I knew it was something obvious that I was missing. Thanks so much!

Comment: But, wait. Doesn't the variable need to be the same throughout that whole portion of code you added? Shouldn't it be `a` instead of `c` in the second half of the OR statement? Or does it not matter?

Comment: I just copied the second part from your code, but those variables are only used within the filter function, to point to the currently being filtered item in the array. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, I started to realize that as I got more coffee in me throughout the morning and was fooling around with the code. Thanks for all your help!